# DialogFlow -CX with React Native

Tags: react-native, rest, dialogflow-cx

Is there any way to implement DialogFlow-cx directly with React native App as DialogFlow ES version does?
I am trying with the REST API also But not working.

I want to Call the Dialogflow CX API from my React-Native App.But I am getting 404, I have downloaded the private key as a JSON file from the service Account also.
Here is a sample code that I have tried

```
let data = {
        "queryInput": {
            "text": {
                "text": "Hi!"
            },
            "languageCode": "en"
        },
        "queryParams": {
            "timeZone": "Asia/Colombo"
        }
    }

 fetch(DEFAULT_BASE_URL + this.projectId +"/locations/"+ this.location + "/agent/"+ this.agentId +"/sessions/" + this.sessionId + ":detectIntent", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.accessToken,
                'charset': "utf-8"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(data)
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("RESPONSE=== ");
                console.log(response);
               // var json = response.json().then(onResult)
            })
            .catch(onError);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the agent to agents in URL and it worked.
Here is a reference doc From Google https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/quick/api